# How to change the position of characters in a String?

Tags: java, string, replace

For example,

```
String a = "horse" ; String b = "eshor" ;
```

How can I change the locations of E and H in string B ?

Note : I cannot use String builder. I want to change them by their position. I need to reveal the first character.

output should be something like :

**shuffled word** : `eshor`

**new word** :`hseor`

Comment: What is the relevance of `String a` here?

Comment: Just to show the original word.

Comment: Are you really asking how to swap two characters?  How do want to specify the characters?  By index?  By character?  What if there is more than one "e"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in java are immutable. Hence, technically, in String b you can not swap spaces of characters.

The only workaround is to

1. Convert String to `char[]`
2. Flip chars in `char[]`
3. Create a new String with reordered `char[]`

Comment: You could use a StringBuilder to simply the process, but the concept is the same...

Answer (score 0):

```
String newWord = word.replace("e","_e_").replace("h","e").replace("_e_","h");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, so I cannot get what your purpose actually is.

You cannot change a String object, because they are immutable. If what you mean with "I cannot use a string builder" is that you cannot use the String object or string casters. then you can operate on chars directly, like this:

```
    char[] cycleChars(String str, int fIndex, int sIndex){
    char[] cArr = str.toCharArray();
    char cTemp;
        cTemp = cArr[fIndex];
        cArr[fIndex] = cArr[sIndex];
        cArr[sIndex] = cTemp;
        return cArr;
}
```

Maybe all you need is a simple op method such as the one above.